# How to get posts of an organization from LinkedIn where Im the admin of the page

Tags: linkedin-api

Being the admin of the company page, how can I access the posts from that company via LinkedIn api

I was made to be an admin to my company profile. I created an app and mapped my company to that app. But the wonder is i just got three permissions to the app:

```
r_emailaddress
r_liteprofile
w_member_social
```

But I read that to fetch the company updates, I should use UGC Api. When I read the api documentation, it states that I need to have `r_member_social` or `r_organization_social` as per the below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api

Can you guys let me know how can i get those permissions to my app?

I tried eventhough with the UGC Api, but it says my app dont have access.

Could anyone help me here to get the information as required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to extend the app permission you should request the access to the `Marketing Developer Platform`. In the `LinkedIn Developer` page, under `Products` you should add the  `Marketing Developer Platform`.
When they grant you the new product, the new permission should be improved like:

```
r_emailaddress
w_share
r_ads
w_organization_social
rw_ads
r_basicprofile
r_liteprofile
r_ads_reporting
r_organization_social
rw_company_admin
rw_organization_admin
w_member_social
```

Also, you can [Retrieve Shares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api#retrieve-shares) with the api using the company id:

```
curl  -X GET \
   -H "Authorization:Bearer token<>" \
 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:company:{id}'
```

Hope this help

Comment: Yes it seems... We need to get marking developer platform without which it is very difficult.

Even for shares api we are getting "Not enough permissions to access: GET-owners /shares"

So I guess without Marketing Developer Platform it will be very difficult to get the acces to posts of my company.

Comment: Hi @KarthickShanmugam I think so

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56338792/8631622 Please look into this problem. I did everything I could. But I could not solve this problem @Matteo

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is outdated; At the time of this writing, we need to add the `Community Management API` product to our organization app.

After creating your app and verifying it, we need to request access.

First of all, after adding the `Community Management API` product, you will need an email registered to a custom domain/business email, since LinkedIn does not allow you to register with a personal email. Also note that you are not allowed to have any other API products added to your app.

After adding the product to your LinkedIn app you will be required to pass an application process where LinkedIn will most notably ask for a registered name of an active business. They will then use the provided business name for verifying its active registration.

it looks like this in your LinkedIn app dashboard under `products`:

[image]