# Symfony 2.8 -> 3.4 Upgrade IsGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY') Throws Errors

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, symfony-3.4, symfony-2.8

I'm in the process of upgrading Symfony from 2.8 to 3.4 and I have a Authentication Listener.

The constructor of the listener

```
  public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager, SessionInterface $session, Security $security, LoggerInterface $logger, Redis $redis, $secret)
    {
        $this->entityManager    = $entityManager;
        $this->session          = $session;
        $this->security         = $security;
        $this->logger           = $logger;
        $this->redis            = $redis;
        $this->secret           = $secret;
    }
```

On Request Function which is calling in listener

```
       public function onRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
        {

        //Validate token

        //Get Authorization Header
        $headers = $event->getRequest()->headers;
        $authHeader = $headers->get('Authorization');

        //Check if Header value starts with 'Bearer'
        if($this->startsWith($authHeader, self::$BEARER_HEADER)) {

                // Allow request to be processed by controllers
               //token handler


        } else {

            $securityContext = $this->security;
            if ($securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')) {
                return;
            } else {
                throw new SessionTimeoutException();
            }

        }
    }
```

Service.yml

```
app.token_listener:
    class: Insead\MIMBundle\Listener\AuthTokenListener
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@session", "@security.helper", "@logger", "@redis.authtoken", "%secret%"]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onRequest, priority: 0 }
```

ACL list entry  - security.php

```
  'access_control' => array(
       array('path' => '^/api/(.*?)/login', 'role'=>'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'),
    )
```

im trying to access login route with username and password but i get following error

```
GENERAL EXCEPTION: The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL. in

/var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/AuthorizationChecker.php line 55 
Exception caught by Listener::  
[
  {
    "file": "/var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Security.php",
    "line": 65,
    "function": "isGranted",
    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Authorization\\AuthorizationChecker",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [
      "IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY",
      null
    ]
  },
  {
    "file": "/var/www/src/Insead/MIMBundle/Listener/AuthTokenListener.php",
    "line": 135,
    "function": "isGranted",
    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Security",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [
      "IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"
    ]
  },
  {
    "file": "/var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php",
    "line": 212,
    "function": "onRequest",
    "class": "Insead\\MIMBundle\\Listener\\AuthTokenListener",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [
      null,
      "kernel.request",
      null
    ]
  },
  {
    "file": "/var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php",
    "line": 44,
    "function": "doDispatch",
    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [
      [
        [
          null,
          "onKernelRequest"
        ],
        [
          null,
          "onKernelRequest"
        ],
        [
          null,
          "onRequest"
        ],
        [
          null,
          "onController"
        ],
        [
          null,
          "onKernelRequest"
        ],
        [
          null,
          "onKernelRequest"
        ],
        [
          null,
          "configure"
        ],
        [
          null,
          "onKernelRequest"
        ],
        [
          null,
          "onKernelRequest"
        ],
        [
          null,
          "onKernelRequest"
        ],
        [
          null,
          "onKernelRequest"
        ],
        [
          null,
          "onKernelRequest"
        ],
        [
          null,
          "onKernelRequest"
        ],
        [
          null,
          "onKernelRequest"
        ],
        [
          null,
          "onKernelRequest"
        ],
        [
          null,
          "onKernelRequest"
        ],
        [
          null,
          "onKernelRequest"
        ],
        [
          null,
          "onRequest"
        ]
      ],
      "kernel.request",
      null
    ]
  },
  {
    "file": "/var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php",
    "line": 127,
    "function": "dispatch",
    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [
      "kernel.request",
      null
    ]
  },
  {
    "file": "/var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php",
    "line": 68,
    "function": "handleRaw",
    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [
      {
        "attributes": null,
        "request": null,
        "query": null,
        "server": null,
        "files": null,
        "cookies": null,
        "headers": null
      },
      1
    ]
  },
  {
    "file": "/var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php",
    "line": 200,
    "function": "handle",
    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [
      {
        "attributes": null,
        "request": null,
        "query": null,
        "server": null,
        "files": null,
        "cookies": null,
        "headers": null
      },
      1,
      true
    ]
  },
  {
    "file": "/var/www/web/app.php",
    "line": 29,
    "function": "handle",
    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [
      {
        "attributes": null,
        "request": null,
        "query": null,
        "server": null,
        "files": null,
        "cookies": null,
        "headers": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have spend days on this and i still couldn't figure it out to fix it.

Im sorry if this is already answered question i tried to search and i tried things which were mentioned in various posts and it didn't resolve it. im new to symfony too.

Full Security.php

https://www.codepile.net/pile/7O1LJkpv

AuthTokenListner.php

https://www.codepile.net/pile/Xv1ZMlAP

Comment: Can you share entire security config? Looks like you tried to check role on a page that does not controlled by firewall. (e.g. your firewall's pattern is `/api`, but you check permissions on `/`)

Comment: It sort of sounds like your listener is before called before the authentication listener.  Use "bin/console debug:event-dispatcher kernel.request" to verify nothing strange is going on.  I suppose it is possible that you might need to use $security->getToken() to verify you have a token but you really should not need to.  And definitely comment out the access control section in security.yaml.  If that 'fixes' the problem then add one rule in at a time to isolate where the actual problem is.

Comment: @BoShurik Thanks for the reply. please check the security.php in this link 
https://www.codepile.net/pile/7O1LJkpv

Comment: @Elnur Abdurrakhimov Please look into this problem. I did everything I could. But I could not solve this problem.

Comment: @nifr Please look into this problem. I did everything I could. But I could not solve this problem

Comment: @Cerad Please look into this problem. I did everything I could. But I could not solve this problem

Comment: `if (!$securityContext->getToken() || $securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')) {` probably would work, but its just a workaround. Real problem is hiding somewhere else

Comment: Maybe you have some `render(controller())` calls on the login page, so `if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) return;` would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was with the priority order.

thanks @cerad for giving a clue about it

```
bin/console debug:event-dispatcher kernel.request
```

helped to solve the issue. i was using

```
tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: onKernelResponse, priority: 10 }
```

in Services.yml and it had a conflict with the

```
getSubscribedEvents()
```

therefore i have removed  tags and only kept

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            KernelEvents::REQUEST  => array('onKernelRequest', 10),
        );
    }
```

then i moved authentication listener to the down by giving high priority to other two listeners as same as it was there in symfony 2.8

Thanks all for helping me out on this specially @Pie @Cerad and @BoShurik

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's the securitycontext which has been deprecated / removed. isGranted needs to be called on the authorization checker

```
return $this->get('security.authorization_checker');
```

You  need the 'security.authorization_checker' service.

You then call isGranted on the authorization_checker service.

```
// get the service from the container or pass it in via injection
$authChecker = $this->get('security.authorization_checker');
if ($authChecker->isGranted('IS...')) { ... }
```

I used rector for easier migration. I would highly recommend https://github.com/rectorphp/rector for smooth migration. I can guarantee you will save lots of time by using this tool.

​

https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2019/02/28/how-to-upgrade-symfony-2-8-to-3-4/

Comment: u mean change 
  $securityContext = $this->security;
            if ($securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')) {
                return;
            } else {
                throw new SessionTimeoutException();
            }
to return $this->get('security.authorization_checker'); ?

Comment: @ThilinaDinithFonseka No, check my answer

Comment: @Pie The somewhat new Security class wraps your suggested functionality.

Comment: Hi @Pie i did as you said but then again i was ended up with same error
did it exactly same as Dylan Kas mentioned below

Comment: @Pie Sorry what is both solutions?  Your solution mentioned above and Dylan's Solution is the same right ?

Answer (score 1):

Inject **AuthorizationChecker** to your class

```
protected $authChecker;

public function __construct(AuthorizationChecker $authChecker)
    {
        $this->authChecker = $authChecker;
    }
```

By injecting it in your **service.yml**

```
XXXXXXXXX:
    class: App\XXX\XXXX\XXXXX
    arguments: [ "@security.authorization_checker" ]
```

And then use it to check role using **isGranted**

```
if ($this->authChecker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')) {

}
```

Comment: The Security class wraps the isGranted functionality.

Comment: @dylan thanks for the reply. i did exactly you have stated above and still endup with same error.

Comment: @Cerad saw that you have mentioned the same comment above. what you mean by that?  can you please explain more?