# Is it possible to put two INSERT statements in one SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to get two `INSERT` statement into one SQL query. I tried several things but nothing seems to work. If I look on the internet it seems it has to work. But it doesn't work for me and I get an error. I'm using this code with PDO.

I tried multiple web browsers, multiple types of code and I tried the "BEGIN" and "COMMIT" statement.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO gebruiker (email, wachtwoord, rol_id) VALUES (?, ?, 2); ".
"INSERT INTO huisarts (voornaam, achternaam, email, straatnaam, huisnummer, postcode, plaats, telefoonnummer, uid, rol_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, LAST_INSERT_ID(), 2);";
$pdostatement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
```

Comment: It's not javascript but php concat operator is `.` instead of `+`. Once have a look at your snippet.

Comment: Why do you need 2 inserts in one go, 2 separate inserts can be easier to debug and you can always use a transaction if you need to ensure they are done together.

Comment: Combining 2 unrelated queries in 1 statement does not seem to make a lot of sense so there really is no need to do that. And if the queries are related - for example if the `uid` in the second query is the inserted id of the first -  you would need separate queries to get the value anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO support for multiple queries (PDO\_MYSQL, PDO\_MYSQLND)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd)

Comment: PDO doesn't support multy query so you cannot get what you want to do. Based on your example also a store procedure makes little use

Comment: You say you get an error - what is the error?

Comment: @jeroen, couldn't you also use LAST_INSERT_ID() (as per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/getting-unique-id.html) in that case, in which you do need to combine the two queries into a single call?

Comment: @Creator13 there are no reasons to combine two queries into a single call.

Answer (score 3):

That silly concatenation mistake aside, it is technically possible to run two INSERT queries in one call, but there is **not a single reason to do so**.

Besides, you will need to configure PDO specifically to allow multiple queries which is not advised.

Therefore, just run these two queries as two separate prepared statements.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO gebruiker (email, wachtwoord, rol_id) VALUES (?, ?, 2)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($first_query_data);
$sql = "INSERT INTO huisarts (voornaam, achternaam, email, straatnaam, huisnummer, postcode, plaats, telefoonnummer, uid, rol_id) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, LAST_INSERT_ID(), 2);";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($second_query_data);
```

Comment: "two INSERT queries *into different tables* ", surely?

Comment: stackoverflow.com/q/56338792/8631622 Please look into this problem. I did everything I could. But I could not solve this problem @Your Common Sense

Comment: @Pie you probably confused the link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56338792/symfony-2-8-3-4-upgrade-isgrantedis-authenticated-anonymously-throws-erro @YourCommonSense

Comment: @Pie i don't get it. It's the answer, not question you wrote.

Comment: But that Did not solve this question. This question is still unanswered. @YourCommonSense