# Linkedin Api. How to retrieve own posts

Tags: c#, .net-core, linkedin-api

I need to get the posts from a companies own LinkedIn page for a sort of social wall where their own posts are being displayed. However LinkedIn has a new api since a while and for somehow I cannot get this data out of it.

How can I get my own company posts through the Linkedin Api and do I need special permissions for it?

I'm writing the backend in C# .NET core

Comment: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api#

Comment: Do you have already see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56292978/2270041 ?